# For-loop in Scala - Unit Issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Good morning.

I have been using Scala in Spark for a few months now and I'm stuck on a for-loop giving me a void (i.e., Unit) content. I was wondering if you could help please.
These are the code lines used:

```
val slr = lsresult.split(Array(' ', '\n')).filter(_.startsWith("/data")) // Extraction of File Path starting with "/data"

val slrMap = slr.map(x => 0.until(x.length).filter(x.startsWith("/",_))).map(x => x.slice(5,7)).map{case Vector(a,b)=>(a,b).toString} // Extraction of the position of the third party data collection agency (i.e., sourcename) of the file

// Knowing what is the positioning of the "/" character in the filename help in determining the sourcename. Here, string between 6th and 7th "/" contains the agency's name hence "slice (5,7)"

val charStart= slrMap.map(_.slice(1,3).toInt)

val charStop= slrMap.map(_.slice(4,6).toInt)
```

here is the method which returns Unit

```
def sourcename = {for (a<-Range(0,slr.length)) {print(slr{a}.slice(charStart{a}, charStop{a}))};}
```

When executing the last line, I get

> sourcename: Unit

However, when I thereafter type *sourcename*, it does produce what I want (i.e., displays the sourcenames sought after) but still consider it as Unit which prevents me from turning it into String.

Your help on this is most appreciated.

Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write `yield` at the end

**for-comprehension syntax**

normally `for comprehension` looks like this

```
for {
 a <- something
 b <- something if a > 10
} yield b
```

In your case

```
for {
 a <- 0 to slr.length
} yield slr(a).slice(charStart(a), charStop(a))
```

Comment: Thanks Pamu. However I get this

scala> for (a<-Range(0,slr.length)) {print(slr{a}.slice(charStart{a}, charStop{a}))} yield a;
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'yield' found.
       for (a<-Range(0,slr.length)) {print(slr{a}.slice(charStart{a}, charStop{a}))} yield a;

Comment: @ChristianIvaha .. your for comprehension would be `for {
 a <- 0 to slr.length
} yield slr(a).slice(charStart(a), charStop(a))`

Comment: He's using an actual for-loop and not a for-comprehension by the way. He just needs to actually return some value. A for-loop doesn't return anything.

Comment: @marstran there is no `for-loop` in scala ... its `for-comprehension`

Comment: @pamu This is not a for-comprehension: `for (i <- (1 to 5)) { println(i) }`. This gets compiled to a standard Java for-loop. It returns `Unit` in Scala.

Comment: @marstran .... I think we can use ... monad in place of `i <- (1 to 5)` ... which is not possible in regular for loop

Comment: @pamu You can use an `Iterable` I guess. Just like you can with a for-each loop in Java. `for (String s : stringCollection)`. I'm not sure about monads that are not iterables.

Comment: @marstran does regular for loop take this  `for (a <- Future {1}) { println(s"$a")}`

Comment: @marstran ... `for-loop` is a special case of `for-comprehension`

Comment: @pamu I know it is a special case. My point was just that he was using that special case, and not a normal for-comprehension. That was the reason his function was returning `Unit`.

Comment: @marstran ... ya true